# mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you have 0.9.3

Tags: mysql, django

It's a bit weird. My project is working all the time and Just today morning got this issue.

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Users..\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "Users..\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "Users..\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "Users..\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "Users..\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "Users..\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "Users..\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "Users..\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "Users..\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "Users..\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "Users..\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "Users..\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "Users..\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "Users..\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 121, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "Users..\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "Users..\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 208, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "Users..\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "Users..\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 207, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "Users..\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "Users..\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "Users..\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 38, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured('mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you have %s.' % Database.__version__)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you have 0.9.3.
```

I installed `mysqlclient` by using wheel.

wheel : mysqlclient-1.4.2-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl

Python version: 3.7.3

When I install again wheel, It says "Requirement already satisfied:... "

but when I run project its says require `mysqlclient` msg.

I don't want to edit base.py.Please, Any Idea?

Comment: Did you try updating the `mysqlclient`? `pip3 install -U mysqlclient`?

Comment: @PedramParsian Yep, but I got the error msg ` Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory`. When I search for this error, the solution is to install wheel. when the install wheel got error msg again.